# Write the Hamilton Jacobi Bellman equation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider the following stochastic optimal control problem.

\begin{equation}
V(t,x) = \max_{u}\,\, \log \left(\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{T} u^{2}(t)dt\right]\right)
\end{equation}

subject to the dynamic contsraint

\begin{equation}
dx(t) = x(t)[(r + u(\mu-r))dt + \sigma u w(t)] \, ; \,\,x(0)=x>0
\end{equation}

where $u$ is the control process to be chosen, $\mu, r, 
\sigma$ are positive constants and $w$ is a standard Brownian motion. My question is how to write the HJB equation for this problem.

My approach this far

\begin{align}
V_t(t,x) + x(r + u(\mu-r))V_{x}(t,x) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}x^{2}V_{xx} + \log(u^{2})
\end{align}
where $V_{t}, V_{x}, V_{xx}$ respresent the partial derivatives of the function $V$ with respect to $t,x$. Is this ok ?